# Loading javascript plugin in B2B area after openning the Orderlist Table

Tags: javascript, shopware, shopware6

I wrote a simple javascript code in shopware 6 and I want to fire it up when I open the Order list Table in B2B area. In Order List area when I click on add or I edit an already added order list, it opens a modal window as General Information, then after I click on Positions it loads the same modal window but with different content. I think using Ajax. And again after clicking on "Add Line Item" it loads again another content. I took a look at Network tab and I realized that it loads actually not only data but the whole HTML for the content. And here is the problem. I have a javascript code and I want to fire it when for example the page "Positions - Add line item" is showed, because I added a button to every row to do something with javascript. I added my defined css selector for example `data-my-selector` to the twig file `_grid-table.html.twig` like this `data-my-selector="true"`. But it does not fire my javascript code at all. In other places, that has static html codes, it works, but when this html is loaded usigin ajax , it does not work.
How can I solve this problem ?